# Convert OPUS to PCM in Android Studio

Tags: java, android-studio, audio, pcm, opus

As one of the components of my app, I need to be able to convert an opus file to mp3. After much looking around, I figured the best approach would be to convert the opus file into raw PCM data and then convert the PCM data to an mp3 file. After experimenting with some libraries, I'm stuck on the first part. I can't figure out how to decode the opus file (with or without the help of libraries that I could find). Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use ffmpeg for this. Do you need examples? I would've suggested you used MediaCodec, but the codecs are highly device dependent and what works on one device might not work on another

Comment: @AdebayoJagunmolu I couldn't figure out how to use FFmpeg in android studio and the GitHub repos that acted as wrappers didn't seem to support opus.

Comment: I think I can make a Java wrapper that will do just what you want, complete with the ffmpeg library bundled. I'll upload it to github and share the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much continued looking, I found a library that is a wrapper for FFmpeg that successfully takes care of the whole conversion from OPUS to MP3 - https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android. It also includes a useful [example class](https://github.com/bravobit/FFmpeg-Android/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/nl/bravobit/ffmpeg/example/ExampleActivity.java) showing how to use it.